# Package for aggregating external packages in meteor.js

Tags: meteor, meteor-packages, meteor-react

I am creating meteor app and I decided to separate it into packages, so I can take control of file loading order.
However, many packages have common dependencies(other external packages) like `react` or `meteorhacks:flow-router`. I want to create main `myapp:app` package with all these dependencies, that other packages in my app will imply.

This is `app` package.js:

```
Package.describe({
    name: 'myapp:app',
    version: '0.0.1'
});


Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.2.1');

    // All external packages that will be used by other local packages
      api.use([
          'twbs:bootstrap',
      ], 'client');

      api.use([
          'ecmascript',
          'react',
          'meteorhacks:flow-router'
      ], ['client', 'server']);
});
```

An I have package `myapp:taskslist` that imply `myapp:app`:

```
Package.describe({
    name: 'myapp:taskslist',
    version: '0.0.1'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.2.1');

    api.imply(['myapp:app']);

    api.addFiles([
        'client/tasksList.jsx',
        'client/task.jsx',
        'main.jsx'
    ], ['client']);
});
```

However it doesn't work. I have an error `No plugin known to handle file 'client/taskList.jsx'` because `myapp:tasksList`, does not have `react` plugin installed. Shouldn't `api.imply()` share `react` to `myapp:tasksList` package? What's good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, no `imply` does not expose `react` to `myapp:tasksList`

You need to think of it like this:

```
IMPLY passes references OUT
USE takes references IN
```

All the imply in `myapp:tasksList` is doing is allowing whatever uses `myapp:tasksList` to have access to `myapp:app`.

In order for you to use `myapp:app` (and all the references it exposes) in `myapp:tasksList` you also need to add

```
  api.use([
      'myapp:app',
  ]);
```

to `myapp:tasksList`